# Display Data Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i have xml file which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test1.xsl"?>
<products>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 55 </node>
            <node> 59 </node>
            <node> 72 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-08-03 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 1 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 72 </node>
            <node> 19 </node>
            <node> 49 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-10-25 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 2 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node> 
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
            <node> 12 </node>
            <node> 548 </node>
            <node> 112 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
            <node> 2013-08-12 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <name> test </name>
            <product_id> 3 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
</products>
```

i have written this xslt to display all the data of product where the `dist_value\node < 50` and that will give the output data of product `2 & 3`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
    <body>

     <table border="1">
      <tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product DATA</th></tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="products/node/node" />
     </table>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="products/node/node/dist_value[node &lt; 50]">
   <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="//product_id" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="products/node/node/*" /></td> 
   </tr>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am beginner to the xslt some thing is wrong here

i want output something like this

```
Product ID  |   Product DATA
--------------------------------
2           |dist_value  => 72
            |               19
            |               79
            |reg_str_dt =>  2013-10-25 17:29:00
            |product_id => 2
```

with product 3 containg name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option that is a little more flexible when it comes to the different elements that can appear in `/products/node/node`. It's also more flexible with the number of `node` elements inside the children of `/products/node/node`.

**XML Input** (modified to show a couple of additional test values to show display)

```
<products>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
                <node> 55 </node>
                <node> 59 </node>
                <node> 72 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <node> 2013-08-03 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 1 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
                <node> 72 </node>
                <node> 19 </node>
                <node> 49 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <node> 2013-10-25 17:29:00 </node>
                <node>additional test value 1</node>
                <node>additional test value 2</node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <product_id> 2 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node> 
    <node>
        <node>
            <dist_value>
                <node> 12 </node>
                <node> 548 </node>
                <node> 112 </node>
            </dist_value>
            <reg_str_dt>
                <node> 2013-08-12 17:29:00 </node>
            </reg_str_dt>
            <name> test </name>
            <product_id> 3 </product_id>
        </node>
    </node>
</products>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/products" priority="1">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Product DATA</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node[node/dist_value/node &lt; 50]"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/node">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="product_id"/>
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name(*[1])"/> --></td> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[1]/*[1]"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::product_id)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--These 2 templates will handle the data on the same
    row as the Product ID.-->
    <xsl:template match="node/node/*[1]" priority="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="newrow"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node/node/*[1]/*[1]" mode="newrow"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="newrow">
        <xsl:call-template name="dataRow"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node/node/*/*[not(position()=1)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="dataRow"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dataRow">
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </tr>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::node)]">
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/> --></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output** (code)

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th colspan="2">Product DATA</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td>dist_value --&gt;</td>
            <td> 72 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 19 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 49 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>reg_str_dt --&gt;</td>
            <td> 2013-10-25 17:29:00 
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>additional test value 1</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>additional test value 2</td>
               </tr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 3 </td>
            <td>dist_value --&gt;</td>
            <td> 12 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 548 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td> 112 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>reg_str_dt --&gt;</td>
            <td> 2013-08-12 17:29:00 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>name --&gt;</td>
            <td> test </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**HTML Output** (display in IE)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your template select statements slightly.
In your matching statement you are selecting the `<dist_value>` nodes, so in the rest of the template, the select statements need to be relative to that `<dist_value>` node, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="products/node/node/dist_value[node &lt; 50]">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="../product_id" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:for-each select="./node">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:value-of select="../reg_str_dt/node" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to know about XSLT is that it has the concept of built-in templates. These templates will be used if it is looking for a template to match an element but one is not present in your XSLT. In your case you start of by looking for **node** elements

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/node/node" />
```

However, your template is matching **dist_value** elements

```
<xsl:template match="products/node/node/dist_value[node &lt; 50]">
```

This means XSLT will start using built in templates, which will output the text of the element, and then process any children. You probably should be doing something like this to match the **node** element.

```
<xsl:template match="products/node/node[dist_value/node &lt; 50]">
```

Although you would also need a template to match **node** elements where the **dist_value** was not less than 50. Alternatively you can change you apply-templates to select only the ones you want

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/node/node[dist_value/node &lt; 50]" />
```

Another issue you have is with this line inside your **dist_value** template

```
<xsl:value-of select="//product_id" />
```

The double-slash means it is will look for a **product_id** relative to the root element, and always pick up the first one. You really just need to do this, to look for the product_id relative to the current **node** element

```
<xsl:value-of select="product_id" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>Product ID</th>
                  <th>Product DATA</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="products/node/node[dist_value/node &lt; 50]"/>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="products/node/node">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="product_id"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="dist_value/node"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td/>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="reg_str_dt/node"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td/>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="product_id"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dist_value/node">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#10;')"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product DATA</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 72 19 49 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td> 2013-10-25 17:29:00 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td> 2 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> 3 </td>
            <td> 12 548 112 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td> 2013-08-12 17:29:00 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td/>
            <td> 3 </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code had quite a few things wrong. Focus on learning about the context node, apply templates, and how the processor iterates over the nodes. Also your schema is awkward; if you can, consider replacing "node/node" with "product".

Here is an XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product DATA</th></tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/products/node/node" />
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- ignore the node with dist_value child by default -->
<xsl:template match="node[ dist_value ]" />
<xsl:template match="node[ dist_value[node &lt; 50] ]" priority="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="span" select="1 + count( * )" />
    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="{$span}"><xsl:value-of select="product_id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="name">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> => </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dist_value">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> =&gt; </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:if test="position()>1">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="reg_str_dt">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> =&gt; </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="node" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product_id">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> =&gt; </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is the output HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product DATA</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="center" rowspan="4">2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>dist_value =&gt; 72, 19, 49</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>reg_str_dt =&gt;  2013-10-25 17:29:00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>product_id =&gt;  2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="center" rowspan="5">3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>dist_value =&gt; 12, 548, 112</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>reg_str_dt =&gt;  2013-08-12 17:29:00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>name =&gt;  test</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>product_id =&gt;  3</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```